# Is it possible to implement a serial console via GDB?

Tags: debugging, swd, terminal, gdb

Is it possible to send debugging messages from MCU to PC over SWD via GDB without interrupting the running code (ie. without using breakpoints), like we could do via UART of MCU by sacrificing 2 UART pins?

Comment: You mean Semihosting?

Comment: Similar to semihosting: [OpenOCD DCC](http://openocd.org/doc/html/Architecture-and-Core-Commands.html#softwaredebugmessagesandtracing), or SEGGER RTT. Both define a debug channel over JTAG/SWD that works in addition to gdb.

Comment: @Jeroen3 It seems so, yes. I've searched my toolchains with the keyword "Semihosting" and I found [this from stlink](https://github.com/texane/stlink/issues/674#issuecomment-369554231), [this from ChibiOS](http://www.chibios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1156).

Comment: @Jeroen3 You may duplicate your comment as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: I have to say that this seems to me like asking how to make a Tesla into a tricycle. Debugging with SWD is so much more powerful than using print statements. With a decent IDE you should be able to trace whatever activity you want.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Every approach can be useful in its context. For example, at the moment I'm struggling with a breakpoint problem: If I place a breakpoint inside a while-true loop, after a communication function, there seems no communication physically takes place between the MCU and the target. If I remove the breakpoint, I can monitor the communication via a logic analyzer. In this case a `print` statement would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by something is called semihosting. How this is implemented depends on the specific devices and software you are using.

It works by using an SVC and BKPT instructions to trigger an action from the debugger host.